# Invalid AES Key length:39bytes

Tags: java, aes, cryptoapi

I am new to java. I am doing encryption and decryption of video files. When I provide a key of small length it works fine without any error. If I gave key of greater length it throws error.

```
private static void doCrypto(int cipherMode, String key, File inputFile,
        File outputFile) throws CryptoException {
    try {    
        Key secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(cipherMode, secretKey);         
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);

        byte[] inputBytes = new byte[(int) inputFile.length()];
        inputStream.read(inputBytes);

        byte[] outputBytes = cipher.doFinal(inputBytes);

        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        outputStream.write(outputBytes);            
        inputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();

    } catch(NoSuchPaddingException|NoSuchAlgorithmException|InvalidKeyException | BadPaddingException| IllegalBlockSizeException | IOException ex) {
        throw new CryptoException("Error encrypting/decrypting file",ex);
    }
```

I am getting the error caused by: `java.security.InvalidKeyException: Invalid AES key length: 39 bytes`

Please help me to fix the error in the below code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a specific key with a supported length, which means your key has to be either

- 128 bit
- 192 bit
- 256 bit
- ...

long. Yours is (see the error message) only 39 byte long.

So you need to convert the `String` (key) (or better `hash` the key before) into an array of `byte` and take the first n (where n is one of the values above) `byte` out of it.

```
import java.security.*;

byte[] bytesOfMessage = key.getBytes("UTF-8");
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
byte[] b = md.digest(bytesOfMessage); //Returns the SHA 256 hash and converts it into byte
// Continue with your code
Key secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(b , "AES");
...
```

Comment: I am getting the error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10

Comment: Thanks for the reply Janes. Its works fine. When I decrypt the file it says parameters missing.

Comment: I think you'll find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6669181/why-does-my-aes-encryption-throws-an-invalidkeyexception