# Java Cipher padding Error

Tags: java, multithreading, encryption

I am new to java and trying to encrypt and decrypt two text messages using `Cipher` and `SecretKey` as shown in the code bellow(Line 241, at the very bottom). Whenever I tries to `Decrypt` this encrypted message, I get an error saying:
`javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded`
`javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 8 when decrypting with padded cipher`
I am using 3 Threads in this code and two buffers/queues called q1 and q2. At first, I put a message in a buffer/queue. Then in the next class, I retrieve that message and encrypt it, and send to the next class. Then that class will put it in a buffer/queue again. Finally, at the last class, it will retrieve from the buffer and decrypt it. This is where the problem happens. There is a Synchronization error going on. I have been trying to figure this error for many days now and no luck. Other online documentations didn't help either. I would greatly appreciate if you could edit this code or show me with an example

```
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.Signature;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;



class Q5 { //Queue/Buffer   
    byte[] shipmentConfirmation;//will include the actual message content been delivered
    boolean valueSet = false;
    synchronized byte[] get() 
    {       
        while(!valueSet) 
        try 
        {
            wait();
        } 
        catch(InterruptedException e) 
        {
            System.out.println("InterruptedException caught");
        }
        //System.out.println("Got: " + n);
        valueSet = false;
        notify();
        return shipmentConfirmation;
    }
    synchronized void put(byte[] shipmentCinfirm) 
    {
        while(valueSet)
        try 
        {
            wait();
        } 
        catch(InterruptedException e) 
        {
            System.out.println("InterruptedException caught");
        }
        this.shipmentConfirmation = shipmentCinfirm;
        valueSet = true;
        //System.out.println("Put: " + n);
        notify();
    }
}

class Global5{
    public static int sendcouter = 0;
    public static SecretKey secret_Key;
    public static Cipher desCipher;
}


//<<security pattern>> SymmetricEncryptionEncryptor
class SecurityEncryptor//<<security>> Encryptor
{
    static byte[] Encryptor(byte shipmentConfirmation[],Cipher c) throws Exception //Encryptor
    {       
        byte[] ciphertext = SecurityEncryptionAlgorithm.EncryptionAlgorithm(shipmentConfirmation,c,Global5.secret_Key);
        return ciphertext;
    }   
}
class SecurityEncryptionAlgorithm//<<security>> EncryptionAlgorithm
{
    static byte[] EncryptionAlgorithm(byte shipmentConfirmation[],Cipher c,SecretKey sk) throws Exception 
    {
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sk);
        return c.doFinal(shipmentConfirmation);
    }
}



//<<security pattern>> aSecureAsynchronousMCReceiverConnector
class SecurityDecryptor//<<Security>> Decryptor
{
    static byte[] Decryptor(byte EncryptedShipmentConfirmation[],Cipher c,SecretKey sk) throws Exception //Decryptor
    {
        byte[] ct = SecurityDecryptionAlgorithm.DecryptionAlgorithm(EncryptedShipmentConfirmation,c,sk);
        return ct;
    }   
}
class SecurityDecryptionAlgorithm//<<Security>> DecryptionAlgorithm
{
    static byte[] DecryptionAlgorithm(byte EncryptedShipmentConfirmation[],Cipher c,SecretKey sk) throws Exception 
    {
        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, sk);
        return c.doFinal(EncryptedShipmentConfirmation);
    }
}



public class testFigure1 { //Main
       public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {          
            Q5 q1 = new Q5();//creating buffer/queue
            Q5 q2 = new Q5();

            System.out.println("How many messages to send: ");
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            int input = in.nextInt();//Get input from the supplier          

            aSupplierInterface Supplier = new aSupplierInterface(q1, input);    
            aSecuritySenderCoordinator SenderCoordinator = new aSecuritySenderCoordinator(q1, input, q2);           
            aSecurityReceiverCoordinator receive = new aSecurityReceiverCoordinator(q2, input);   
            Supplier.t_pro.join();
            SenderCoordinator.t_coordinator5.join();
            receive.t_SecurityReceiverCoordinator5.join();
            System.out.println("End of Program!");
       }   
}

class aSupplierInterface  implements Runnable //<<application Component>> aSupplierInterface
{
    Q5 q;   
    int supinput;
    Thread t_pro;//pro to represent producer or suppler
    aSupplierInterface(Q5 qq, int input)
    {
        supinput = input;
        this.q = qq;
        t_pro = new Thread(this, "Producer");
        t_pro.start();
    }
    public void run() 
    {
        int i = 0;
        String shipment;
        byte[] shipmentConfirmation;
        while(i<supinput)
        {
            i++;
            shipment = "This is the Delivery Number: "+ i;
            shipmentConfirmation = shipment.getBytes();

            q.put(shipmentConfirmation);//Putting supplier's goods in a queue/buffer            
        }   
    }       
}

class aSecuritySenderCoordinator implements Runnable //<<security coordinator>> aSecuritySenderCoordinator
{
    Q5 q;
    Q5 q2;
    Thread t_coordinator5;
    int supinput;

    public aSecuritySenderCoordinator(Q5 qq, int input, Q5 q2) throws Exception
    {       
        supinput=input;
        this.q = qq;    
        this.q2=q2;
        t_coordinator5 = new Thread(this, "coordinator5");
        t_coordinator5.start();
    }

    public void run() 
    {
        byte[] pkShipmentConfirmation;
        byte[] shipmentConfirmation;
        int i = 0;
        while(i<supinput) 
        {               
            i++;

                //Getting goods that supplier has put in the queue previously
            pkShipmentConfirmation=q.get();//This will contain content of the message/delivery you are sending
            KeyGenerator keygen;
            try {
            keygen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES");
            Global5.sendcouter++;//To Create the key once
            if(Global5.sendcouter==1)//Create once
            {
                Global5.secret_Key = keygen.generateKey();
                Global5.desCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
            }           
            //String st1 = new String(pkShipmentConfirmation);//just to print a message
            //System.out.println("*ORIGINAL MESSAGE:"+st1);    
            shipmentConfirmation = SecurityEncryptor.Encryptor(pkShipmentConfirmation,Global5.desCipher);//Encrypting 


            new anAsynchronousMCReceiver(q2, shipmentConfirmation);     

            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}




class anAsynchronousMCReceiver 
{ //<<communication pattern>> anAsynchronousMCReceiver
       Q5 q;

       anAsynchronousMCReceiver( Q5 q2, byte[] shipmentConfirm) throws Exception
       {
           this.q = q2;
           q.put(shipmentConfirm);  //Entering received data in to the Queue/Buffer 
       }
}



class aSecurityReceiverCoordinator implements Runnable//<<security coordinator>> aSecurityReceiverCoordinator
{       
    Thread t_SecurityReceiverCoordinator5;  
    Q5 q;
    int supinput;
    byte[]encryptedShipmentConfirmation;
    public aSecurityReceiverCoordinator(Q5 q2, int input) throws Exception
    {  
        this.q = q2;    
        supinput = input;
        t_SecurityReceiverCoordinator5 = new Thread(this, "SecurityReceiverCoordinator5");
        t_SecurityReceiverCoordinator5.start();

    }
    public void run() 
    {
        try {
            int i = 0;
            while(i<supinput) 
            {           
                i++;
                encryptedShipmentConfirmation = q.get();                
                byte[] confirmation = SecurityDecryptor.Decryptor(encryptedShipmentConfirmation,Global5.desCipher,Global5.secret_Key);//ERROR HAPPENS HERE              
                String shipConfirmation = new String(confirmation);

                System.out.println("AT DelivertyOrder: " +  shipConfirmation);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

If you copy and past this program, it will run on your computer

Comment: When I run it sometimes it fails and sometimes it doesn't. That indicates unsafe parallelism is occurring. Recheck your synchronization design.

Comment: This is more or less a code dump. Please walk us through the code and describe its purpose.

Comment: (0.) Nice seeing UML having been used. (1.) wait/notify I rarely encounter. A wait inside a synchronized seems asking for deadlocks. (3) `new String(byte[], Charset)/String.getBytes(Charset)`. Otherwise the computer where this runs determines the charset. Best StandardCharsets.UTF_8. (4) Name conventions are quite strict in java: class names start with a capital, variables small letter. (5) Count me out delving into this.

Comment: @JoopEggen A `wait()` that *isn't* inside a `synchronized` is a basic error, and a `wait()` that is inside two `synchronized`'s, as here, is perfectly fine as long as everybody acquires the same locks in the same order.

Comment: @EJP of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Multi-threading issue:

You have to be careful if you are using same instance of `Cipher` object for encryption or decryption, **and specially** when more than 1 thread will access the same `Cipher` object (situation in your case) because it internally uses buffers, paddings etc. so even if you specify appropriate padding scheme, like you were specifying `PKCS5Padding` OR you do not specify any padding (using `AES/ECB/NoPadding` or using ECB mode `DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding`), **you are most likely to get** the exception you were getting - `javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded` and `javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 8 when decrypting with padded cipher` because internally Cipher object was getting messed up.

Now, since you were using same `Cipher` object so even though you specified padding etc. correctly but still you were getting padding related exceptions because it was same object.

### Cryptography issue:

If `CBC` mode is used for Cipher object then a `IvParameterSpec` object should also be provided otherwise you are likely to run into exceptions like `java.security.InvalidKeyException`.

[Read this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6669181/why-does-my-aes-encryption-throws-an-invalidkeyexception).

Also, it is recommended to use `CBC` mode over `ECB` mode.

[Read this answer.](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/12529/what-are-the-advantages-of-cbc-over-ecb)

### Updated code

So, your final code looks as below, which will run with no exception, however number of messages you specify with the answer to - `How many messages to send:`

*P.S.: I have done some code clean up to close your `Scanner` object etc., you should pay attention to these kind of things as well*

```
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;



class Q5 { //Queue/Buffer   
    byte[] shipmentConfirmation;//will include the actual message content been delivered
    boolean valueSet = false;
    synchronized byte[] get() 
    {       
        while(!valueSet) 
        try 
        {
            wait();
        } 
        catch(InterruptedException e) 
        {
            System.out.println("InterruptedException caught");
        }
        //System.out.println("Got: " + n);
        valueSet = false;
        notify();
        return shipmentConfirmation;
    }
    synchronized void put(byte[] shipmentCinfirm) 
    {
        while(valueSet)
        try 
        {
            wait();
        } 
        catch(InterruptedException e) 
        {
            System.out.println("InterruptedException caught");
        }
        this.shipmentConfirmation = shipmentCinfirm;
        valueSet = true;
        //System.out.println("Put: " + n);
        notify();
    }
}

class Global5{
    public static int sendcouter = 0;
    public static SecretKey secret_Key;
    public static Cipher desCipher;
}


//<<security pattern>> SymmetricEncryptionEncryptor
class SecurityEncryptor//<<security>> Encryptor
{
    static byte[] Encryptor(byte shipmentConfirmation[],Cipher c) throws Exception //Encryptor
    {       
        byte[] ciphertext = SecurityEncryptionAlgorithm.EncryptionAlgorithm(shipmentConfirmation,c,Global5.secret_Key);
        return ciphertext;
    }   
}
class SecurityEncryptionAlgorithm//<<security>> EncryptionAlgorithm
{
    static byte[] EncryptionAlgorithm(byte shipmentConfirmation[],Cipher c,SecretKey sk) throws Exception 
    {
        byte[] iv = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
        IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sk, ivspec);
        return c.doFinal(shipmentConfirmation);
    }
}



//<<security pattern>> aSecureAsynchronousMCReceiverConnector
class SecurityDecryptor//<<Security>> Decryptor
{
    static byte[] Decryptor(byte EncryptedShipmentConfirmation[],Cipher c,SecretKey sk) throws Exception //Decryptor
    {
        byte[] ct = SecurityDecryptionAlgorithm.DecryptionAlgorithm(EncryptedShipmentConfirmation,c,sk);
        return ct;
    }   
}
class SecurityDecryptionAlgorithm//<<Security>> DecryptionAlgorithm
{
    static byte[] DecryptionAlgorithm(byte EncryptedShipmentConfirmation[],Cipher c,SecretKey sk) throws Exception 
    {
        byte[] iv = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
        IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, sk, ivspec);
        return c.doFinal(EncryptedShipmentConfirmation);
    }
}



public class testFigure1 { //Main
       public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {          
            Q5 q1 = new Q5();//creating buffer/queue
            Q5 q2 = new Q5();

            System.out.println("How many messages to send: ");
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            int input = in.nextInt();//Get input from the supplier          
            in.close();

            aSupplierInterface Supplier = new aSupplierInterface(q1, input);    
            aSecuritySenderCoordinator SenderCoordinator = new aSecuritySenderCoordinator(q1, input, q2);           
            aSecurityReceiverCoordinator receive = new aSecurityReceiverCoordinator(q2, input);   
            Supplier.t_pro.join();
            SenderCoordinator.t_coordinator5.join();
            receive.t_SecurityReceiverCoordinator5.join();
            System.out.println("End of Program!");
       }   
}

class aSupplierInterface  implements Runnable //<<application Component>> aSupplierInterface
{
    Q5 q;   
    int supinput;
    Thread t_pro;//pro to represent producer or suppler
    aSupplierInterface(Q5 qq, int input)
    {
        supinput = input;
        this.q = qq;
        t_pro = new Thread(this, "Producer");
        t_pro.start();
    }
    public void run() 
    {
        int i = 0;
        String shipment;
        byte[] shipmentConfirmation;
        while(i<supinput)
        {
            i++;
            shipment = "This is the Delivery Number: "+ i;
            shipmentConfirmation = shipment.getBytes();

            q.put(shipmentConfirmation);//Putting supplier's goods in a queue/buffer            
        }   
    }       
}

class aSecuritySenderCoordinator implements Runnable //<<security coordinator>> aSecuritySenderCoordinator
{
    Q5 q;
    Q5 q2;
    Thread t_coordinator5;
    int supinput;

    public aSecuritySenderCoordinator(Q5 qq, int input, Q5 q2) throws Exception
    {       
        supinput=input;
        this.q = qq;    
        this.q2=q2;
        t_coordinator5 = new Thread(this, "coordinator5");
        t_coordinator5.start();
    }

    public void run() 
    {
        byte[] pkShipmentConfirmation;
        byte[] shipmentConfirmation;
        int i = 0;
        while(i<supinput) 
        {               
            i++;

                //Getting goods that supplier has put in the queue previously
            pkShipmentConfirmation=q.get();//This will contain content of the message/delivery you are sending
            KeyGenerator keygen;
            try {
            keygen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES");
            Global5.sendcouter++;//To Create the key once
            if(Global5.sendcouter==1)//Create once
            {
                Global5.secret_Key = keygen.generateKey();
                Global5.desCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            }           
            //String st1 = new String(pkShipmentConfirmation);//just to print a message
            //System.out.println("*ORIGINAL MESSAGE:"+st1);    
            shipmentConfirmation = SecurityEncryptor.Encryptor(pkShipmentConfirmation,Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"));//Encrypting 


            new anAsynchronousMCReceiver(q2, shipmentConfirmation);     

            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}




class anAsynchronousMCReceiver 
{ //<<communication pattern>> anAsynchronousMCReceiver
       Q5 q;

       anAsynchronousMCReceiver( Q5 q2, byte[] shipmentConfirm) throws Exception
       {
           this.q = q2;
           q.put(shipmentConfirm);  //Entering received data in to the Queue/Buffer 
       }
}



class aSecurityReceiverCoordinator implements Runnable//<<security coordinator>> aSecurityReceiverCoordinator
{       
    Thread t_SecurityReceiverCoordinator5;  
    Q5 q;
    int supinput;
    byte[]encryptedShipmentConfirmation;
    public aSecurityReceiverCoordinator(Q5 q2, int input) throws Exception
    {  
        this.q = q2;    
        supinput = input;
        t_SecurityReceiverCoordinator5 = new Thread(this, "SecurityReceiverCoordinator5");
        t_SecurityReceiverCoordinator5.start();

    }
    public void run() 
    {
        try {
            int i = 0;
            while(i<supinput) 
            {           
                i++;
                encryptedShipmentConfirmation = q.get();                
                byte[] confirmation = SecurityDecryptor.Decryptor(encryptedShipmentConfirmation,Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"),Global5.secret_Key);//ERROR HAPPENS HERE              
                String shipConfirmation = new String(confirmation);

                System.out.println("AT DelivertyOrder: " +  shipConfirmation);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Without looking too much at the code, I can see that it's using a shared instance of `Cipher`. `Cipher` is not thread safe and it's used both in `SecurityDecryptionAlgorithm` and `SecurityEncryptionAlgorithm` so it's asking for trouble... and the trouble is that the internal buffer gets corrupted and throws the exception you are showing.

To fix this, just instance cipher on each encryption/decryption (preferred solution), create one instance per thread, or make the static methods from `SecurityDecryptionAlgorithm` and `SecurityEncryptionAlgorithm` synchronized and provide each one with a different instance of `Cipher`.

I would remove `Cipher` from `Global5` and instantiate a new one on each call to encrypt or decrypt.

To make this more visible, this code calls

```
c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sk);
```

and

```
c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, sk);
```

On the same instance... which I'm sure it confuses the cipher even further.